# Unable to display data with __str__

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

This code is part of a larger program .. I am trying to generate a summary that displays the data taken from a user

```
class Mbilling:
   def __init__(self, income, debit = 0, rent = 745):
       self.income = income
       self.debit   = debit
       self.rent    = rent

class Display(Mbilling):

   def listMbilling(self):
       self.m = f"""
            ------------------------------------
            --> Income = {self.income}
            --> Debit  = {self.debit}
            --> Rent   = {self.rent}
            ------------------------------------
                 """

    def __str__(self):
        return self.m
```

and i am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Engineering\#ZicX\#Programming in Python\Basic Python\Tutorials\test.py", line 25, in <module>
    receipt = Display()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'income'
```

When i try these  command:

```
d1 = Mbilling(5000, 0, 750)
receipt = Display()
print(receipt)
```

Need help to understand what's wrong ,, thanks !

Comment: You're creating a `Display()` without passing the arguments you've said it needs. I think in your final snippet you meant to pass the parameters `5000, 0, 750` to `Display()` rather than `Mbilling`. Maybe do some basic reading up on how classes work.

Comment: Shouldn't have the class Display() inherited these attributes form the super class already??

Comment: That's not how classes work, https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: When you create an `Display` instance, you have to pass it the arguments that the class `Mbilling` expect since the subclass is in inheriting the `Mbilling.__init__()` method.

Comment: ``receipt = Display(...)`` is *a* ``Mbilling``. It is not *the* ``Mbilling`` created just before. You must still provide it all the data an ``Mbilling`` needs.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the issue here is a matter of class inheritance. I am by no means a super() expert but here's what I can contribute:

Here is one example:

```
class MethodOne:

def __init__(self):

    self.param_one = "Car"
    self.param_two = 200


class MethodTwo(MethodOne):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def __str__(self):
        self.string_one = f"I have a {self.param_one}." 
        self.string_two = f"{self.param_two} minus 100 equals {self.param_two - 100}!"
        

        return self.string_one + "\n" + self.string_two
```

And here is another example that more closely relates to what you are looking to achieve.

```
class Mbilling:

    def __init__(self, income = 0, debit = 0, rent = 745):
        self.income = income
        self.debit = debit
        self.rent = rent

        print("Hi there. I am the parent")

class Display(Mbilling):

    def __init__(self, income, debit, rent):
        print("Hi, I am the child")
        
        super().__init__()

    
    def listMbilling(self):
        self.m = f"""
            ------------------------------------
            --> Income = {self.income}
            --> Debit  = {self.debit}
            --> Rent   = {self.rent}
            ------------------------------------
                 """
    
    def __str__(self):
        self.listMbilling()
        return self.m

d1 = Display(23, 40, 745)
print(d1)
```

Also, this link is super ;) useful https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-super-in-python

Comment: Take note that ``Display.__init__`` throws away its arguments. It should pass them on to its parent ``__init__``. This code works because ``Mbilling`` was changed to work without input, not because the class ``Display`` or ``Display(23, 40, 745)`` handle arguments properly.